# App Language Changing don't work after publishing in play console?

Tags: java, android, playback

This app has 4 languages. If I install it via android studio or create APK and then install it on any phone, then changing the language works perfectly. But, After publishing on Play Console and downloading from the store, the app changing language doesn't work. Only stays English default

I just added some extra translatable lines in strings of other languages ( string.kurdish, string.german). I do want not it works as changing the language after publishing in-store!

Comment: It could also be that there is a problem with the way that you are attempting to change the language within your app. Could you provide more information about how you are implementing the language change feature in your app?

Comment: if specific language is not installed, then translation will not work. For Example: If Arabic is not installed in user phone, then Arabic translation will not work in your app. After download Arabic in phone, then you need to uninstall and reinstall app from play store. Below solution is working perfectly fine. Thanks @Niranj

Answer (score 5):

When you upload bundle file (.aab) to publish app on Play Store then it will removes localization files based on the user's phone settings during installation.

To avoid this, you need to add below line in **build.gradle** file

```
android {

  bundle {

     language {
       enableSplit = false
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Exactly. I want to add that you can test if this is the problem by adding additional secondary languages to your Android settings. The Play Store should then download the additional languages.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.